# Why do the $\sec$ & $\cosh$ substitutions give different antiderivatives for $\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}} \,?$

Tags: calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

Suppose we want to find

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}\,\mathrm dx.$$

Trigonometric substitution: $$=\ln \left| x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2} \right|$$

Hyperbolic substitution: $$=\cosh^{-1}\left({\frac{x}{a}}\right)=\ln\left({x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}\right)$$

How are they the same when one has the absolute value and one doesn't? Clearly, the first answer is defined for all $|x|>a,$ whereas the second one is defined only for $x>a.$

Comment: But the expression $\;\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}\;$ is defined *within the real numbers* iff $\;x^2>a^2\iff |x|>|a|\;$ ...

Comment: Yes, but why are the answers different? One has absolute values, and one doesn't.

Comment: Also, both answers have different domains. Arcosh is only defined when x > a, but the first answer is defined for |x| > a. For the second answer, $\ln\left({x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}\right)$, put in ANY x < -a, and it will be undefined. That is not the case for $\ln \left| x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2} \right|$.

Comment: remember that for the hyperbolic cosine to have an inverse we **must** restrict its domain, usually to the non-negative reals, so those two expressions are the same in fact.

Comment: Doesn't the hyperbolic cosine have two inverses? $y=\cos(\theta)=\cos(-\theta)$, therefore, $\arccos(y)$ and $-\arccos(y)$. Also, how are both expressions the same when hyperbolic cosine forces us to restrict the domain, more so than the circular trig sub?

Comment: As I've said about, clearly values of x<-a are defined in the first expression, not the second. One answer is more complete, right?

Comment: Anyone? My question hasn't been resolved.

Comment: The hyp. cosine isn't 1-1, thus we must restrict its domain to get a 1-1 function and get its inverse. We usually choose $\;[0,\infty]\;$, but you can choose the non-positive as well. Anyway, there's only *one single* inverse for the hyp. cosine **once we chose** the domain: you don't have two. That's what I meant above and that's why I think this answers your quest.

Comment: It does...thanks!

Comment: But the fact that trig substitution gives a more COMPLETE solution than hyperbolic substitutions  bug me.

Comment: Why not investigate it yourself?  Find an interval where the two answers are different.  Differentiate the two.  Which yields $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}$?

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose we want to find
>
> $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}\,\mathrm dx.$$
>
> Trigonometric substitution: $$=\ln \left| x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2} \right|$$
>
> Hyperbolic substitution:
> $$=\cosh^{-1}\left({\frac{x}{a}}\right)=\ln\left({x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}\right)$$
> the fact that trig substitution gives a more COMPLETE solution than hyperbolic substitutions bug me.

Noting that antiderivatives exist on $(-\infty,-a)\cup(a,\infty)$ and using the hyperbolic substitution $\displaystyle \theta=\operatorname{arccosh} \left(\frac{|x|}a\right):$
\begin{align}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}\,\mathrm
   dx&=\begin{cases}\displaystyle-\operatorname{arccosh}\,\left(-\frac
   x{a}\right)+C_1, &&&x<-a; \\
   \displaystyle\mathrm{arccosh}\,\left(\frac x{a}\right)+C_2,  &&&
x>a \end{cases}
\\&=\begin{cases}\displaystyle-\left[\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2-a^2}-x\right)-\ln (a)\right]+C_1, &&&x<-a; \\
   \displaystyle\left[\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\right)-\ln (a)\right]+C_2,  &&&
x>a \end{cases} 
\\&=\begin{cases}-\ln \left(\sqrt{x^2-a^2}-x\right)+C_1+\ln(a^2), &&&x<-a; \\\ln \left| x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\right|+C_3,  &&&x>a \end{cases}
\\&=\begin{cases}\ln \left( \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}-x}\right)+C_1,&&&x<-a; \\\ln \left| x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\right|+C_3,  &&&x>a \end{cases}
\\&=\begin{cases}\ln \left( -\left(\sqrt{x^2-a^2}+x\right)\right)+C_1,&&&x<-a; \\\ln \left| x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\right|+C_3,  &&&x>a \end{cases}
\\&=\begin{cases}\ln \left| x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\right|+C,&&&x<-a; \\\ln \left| x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\right|+D,  &&&x>a, \end{cases}\end{align} which is the same result as the trigonometric substitution.